# Operation inside tuple - Convert a nested array into flat array

Tags: arrays, scala

I asked a question about how to convert Array("AA", Array("BB", "CC"), "DD") into Array("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"), which was solved by

```
arr.flatMap {
   |   case s: String => Array(s)
   |   case a: Array[String] => a
   | }
```

Now I have data Array((AA, Array(BB, CC), DD)). It looks like an array of tuple which contains a nested array. I want to get the output as Array((AA, BB, CC, DD)), but couldn't figure it out. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: I think the question you ought to be asking yourself is how you ended up with an `Array[Any]` in the first place...

Comment: the data comes from textFileStream:  val lines = ssc.textFileStream(dataDirectory)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
val a = arr.head; Array(a._1, a._2, a._3)... [the rest of your code]
```

Comment: sorry, it's late here - see edited answer and I promise it'll work this time :) - tuples in Scala aren't great for things like that - look at how few functions they have here http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple3

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Suppose we have data:
val data = Array(("AA", Array("BB", "CC"), "DD"))

After following steps:
val x = data match {case Array((a, b, c)) => Array(a, b, c)}
val y = x.flatMap{case s: String => Array(s); case a: Array[String] => a}

I got y: Array[String] = Array(AA, BB, CC, DD)